# Android App shows incompatible with ICS 4.0.4 device Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

Here is the stuff that matters from my Android App Manifest file. I am looking at supporting Android API Level 4 and above with target = 14 supporting all screens.

Developer console shows
API level: 4-16+
Supported screens: small-xlarge
OpenGL textures: all

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WIFI_CHANGE_STATE"/>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>

    <supports-screens 
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true" 
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Here is the [Google Play App link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140316104611/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tooyoou.android&feature=search_result)

Here are the device details for the Device from which when I go to Google Play my App shows incompatible.

Motorola DROID Bionic
Android Vs 4.0.4
Verizon Wireless CDMA

System Version 6.7.230.XT875.Verizon.en.US (Leaked ICS Build for DROID Bionic)
Build Number 6.7.2-223

I have tried turning Copy Protection On/Off from Google Play but same result.

I am unable figure out what is causing this incompatibility with my app and device because Google Play Publishing shows this Device is supported by my release apk.

Is there any chance that me using a leaked ICS build for the Bionic has anything to do with it? It would be very helpful if anyone with 4.0.4 or (Android device running any version of ICS) can try to download the app from Google Play and see if the App is incompatible with their device too or its just me. Other than that suggestions on a way to fix this would be tremendously helpful.

Thanks so much.

**Update: I am using two SDKs with my App - Flurry SDK and Skyhook Wireless SDK jar files both of which are compatible with Android 4.0. Also I have added Android Support Library and compiled the codebase against Android 4.0.3 and the App still is incompatible with the device and build mentioned above running Android v 4.0.4**

Comment: I searched in the market for "tooyoou" on an HTC Evo 4g LTE that is running ICS and your app does not appear in the results.

Comment: @Tim same for me. Any ideas why this is happening given the info above?

Comment: Nope sorry. My only suggestion is try removing the target SDK, I don't see why that would help but worth a shot I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem Solved!

First of all there is nothing wrong in the Manifest or the version of Android SDK I compiled the code base against which is Android 4.1.

I could search for and install the App when I turned Copy Protection OFF from Google Play developer console and waited 30 minutes to 1 hour for the new copy protection setting to take effect. The key here is that after changing the Copy Protection settings you have to wait. This does not take effect immediately.

Previously Copy Protection was ON for Tooyoou and after I wrote to Android developer support I got the clue in their reply email as below.

> If your app no longer appears in Google Play after enabling Copy Protection, please note that our copy protection relies on being able to trust the build of Android that the app is installed on. Therefore, we only show copy-protected apps to known good builds of Android. If a specific port of Android is not a known good build (e.g. some “Custom ROMs”) or the device is rooted, Google Play will not display copy-protected apps to these devices. If the users switch to an official version of Android, they'll be able to see your application again.

Since I am running a custom unreleased ROM on my DROID BIONIC this is what caused the issue. Stock ASOP ICS and Jelly Bean devices were able to download and install the app even when Copy Protection was ON. Copy Protection is a bit tricky for Paid App but since Tooyoou is free there is not much to care about.

Also note Copy Protection is supposedly being deprecated soon and Licensing feature in the Android SDK is the way to go for Paid App copy protection.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding android:xlargeScreens="true" to support-screens?

Comment: I can add that but Droid Bionic or HTC EVO are not xlarge screen category devices though.

Comment: Make sure you don't have <compatible-screens> set too http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

Comment: I don't have compatible screens in the manifest but have support screens.